# Why does convergence in $L^{p_2}$ imply convergence in $L^{p_1}$ if $p_1\leq p_2$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},X$ be random variables on the same prob. space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

We say that $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in $L^p$ if

1. for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$: $X_n \in L^p$
2. $X \in L^p$
3. $\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|^p) \underset{n\to\infty}{\to} 0$

Now, the book I am reading claims that for any $p_1\leq p_2$ one has that if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^{p_2}$ it also converges in $L^{p_1}$ (with no other assumptions made).

I can see why 3. is true, however I find it hard to believe that 1. and 2. also have to hold. Afaik, one has (for $p_1 < p_2$) $L^{p_1} \subsetneq L^{p_2}$, so it might very well be possible that they don't hold.

Am I missing something or is the statement indeed false?

Comment: So you know that $L^p\subseteq L^q$ for $q\leq p$ in a probability space? Apply Holder with right chosen exponents and you will get it.

Comment: Or Jenson’s inequality with $f(x)=x^{p/q}$.

Comment: Take $p_1=0$ and $p_2=1$ and the result does not hold, say, for $X=1$ and $X_n=1+1/n$ with prob 1, since $E[|X_n-X|]\rightarrow 0$ but $E[|X_n-X|^0]\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's the other way around. If $1\leq p_1< p_2<\infty$ and the measure space is finite (a probability space is finite, so here it is fine) then $L^{p_2}\subseteq L^{p_1}$. This follows from Holder's inequality. If $X\in L^{p_2}$ then:

$\int_{\Omega} |X|^{p_1} dP(\omega)\leq (\int_{\Omega} |X|^{p_2}dP(\omega))^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}(\int_{\Omega}1^rdP(\omega))^\frac{1}{r}<\infty$

Where $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{p_1}{p_2}=1$.

Comment: Oh...I guess this is a little embarassing for me :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, and $q<p$, then $L^{p}\subset L^{q}$.

Indeed, let $f\in L^p$, then $$\int |f|^q=\int_{|f|\leq 1} |f|^q+\int_{|f|>1}|f|^q\leq \int_{|f|\leq 1} 1+\int_{|f|>1}|f|^p\leq \mu(\Omega)+\int_{|f|>1}|f|^p<\infty$$